# Align along multiple columns, some aligned left, some aligned right

Tags: alignat

[image]

This is an annotated screenshot of what I currently have. I am using the alignat environment, and I have three columns (drawn in blue by hand) along which I am aligning my things. In order to get stuff to look as I want, I have added some hspace after some of the columns (labeled "hspace" by hand). The issue I am having is that I want some of my things to align all to the left of the column (my \iff for example), but I want the LHS (Left Hand Side) of my equations to align to the LEFT of the equals (< actually) sign, and the RHS of my equation to align to the RIGHT of equals sign (what I want changed is in red). How can I do this?

The latex for what is above is here:

```
\newcommand\size{2} 
\begin{alignat*}{4}
\quad & \hspace{\size cm} \mod{\frac{z-\alpha}{z+\alpha}} && < 1 &&& \text{}\\
%
\iff \quad & \hspace{\size cm} \frac{\mod{z-\alpha}}{\mod{z+\alpha}} &&< 1 &&& \text{}\\
%
\iff \quad & \hspace{\size cm} \mod{z-\alpha} && < \mod{z+\alpha} &&& \qquad \qquad \text{ as $\mod{z+\alpha} > 0$}\\
%
\iff \quad & \hspace{\size cm} \mod{z-\alpha}^2 && < \mod{z+\alpha}^2 &&& \qquad \qquad \text{ as $\mod{z+\alpha} > 0$}\\
%
\iff \quad & \hspace{\size cm} (z-\alpha)\overline{(z-\alpha)} && < (z+\alpha)\overline{(z+\alpha)} &&& \qquad \qquad \text{}\\
%
\iff \quad & \hspace{\size cm}(z-\alpha)\overline{(z-\alpha)} && < (z+\alpha)\overline{(z+\alpha)} &&& \qquad \qquad \text{}\\
\end{alignat*}
```

Comment: I have not your problem with your code and I have "mod x" instead of "|x|". Wouldn't it have to do with to rest of your code (interference with other packages etc) ?[![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay1oz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay1oz.png)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! When placed in a default environment with `\documentclass{article}` and `\usepackage{amsmath]`, the code you provide does not output what you show. Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that, if compiled, produces the output you show so that others can better help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect you're redefining `\mod` to give the absolute value. Don't.

You need just three pairs of columns.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for context

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand{\size}{0}% initialize

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]
\renewcommand\size{2}% <-- don't forget
\begin{alignat*}{3}
&& \hspace{\size cm}
  \abs*{\frac{z-\alpha}{z+\alpha}} & < 1 \\
%
&{\Longleftrightarrow} & \hspace{\size cm}
  \frac{\abs{z-\alpha}}{\abs{z+\alpha}} & < 1 \\
%
&{\Longleftrightarrow} & \hspace{\size cm}
  \abs{z-\alpha} & < \abs{z+\alpha} && \qquad \qquad \text{as $\abs{z+\alpha} > 0$} \\
%
&{\Longleftrightarrow} & \hspace{\size cm}
  \abs{z-\alpha}^2 & < \abs{z+\alpha}^2 && \qquad \qquad \text{as $\abs{z+\alpha} > 0$} \\
%
&{\Longleftrightarrow} & \hspace{\size cm}
  (z-\alpha)\overline{(z-\alpha)} & < (z+\alpha)\overline{(z+\alpha)} \\
%
&{\Longleftrightarrow} & \hspace{\size cm}
  (z-\alpha)\overline{(z-\alpha)} & < (z+\alpha)\overline{(z+\alpha)}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Note `{\Longleftrightarrow}` instead of `\iff` (that adds space around the arrow) and the removed space before “as”, so you can better control the spacings.

[image]